# Namespace - scope python

Tags: python, scope, namespaces, closures

I am pretty confused about how the rules of LEGB apply here. I
understand that Local can be inside a function or class method, for
example. Enclosed can be its enclosing function, e.g., if a function
is wrapped inside another function. Global refers to the uppermost
level of the executing script itself, and Built-in are special names
that Python reserves for itself. I just don't get how it applies here and   > why the output is what it is.thanks

```
a = 'global'

def outer():

    def len(in_var):
        print('called my len() function: ')
        l = 0
        for i in in_var:
            l += 1
        return l

    a = 'local'

    def inner():
        global len
        nonlocal a
        a += ' variable'
    inner()
    print('a is', a)
    print(len(a))

outer()

print(len(a))
print('a is', a)
```

output

```
('a is', 'local')
called my len() function: 
5
15
('a is', 'global variable')
```

Comment: I'm getting different output in python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting following result with 3.4.2

```
a is local variable
called my len() function: 
14
6
a is global
```

For the explanation, actually you got almost all the important details but the key point is `nonlocal`  statement causes the identifier to refer to previously bound variable in the nearest enclosing scope, which means `a` in `inner()` refers to and affects `a = 'local'` so after that; `print('a is', a)` uses a as `local variable` and have length 14. However in global scope `a = 'global'` is still effective.

Can you please share the details of your environment that we can investigate the difference?

Comment: HI Heval. thank you. I use PyCharm 2016.2 pointing to Anaconda for the modules. The version of python is 2.7 though.
I am still confused how the increment happens, and the order of output although i thought i understood the rules..

Comment: Are you sure about python 2.7? Afaik, nonlocal is not available for that version so you should be getting error.

Comment: yes PyCharm has that forward compatibility thing I think. PyCharm will check the code compatibility against two or more Python versions specified.

Comment: Never heard that before :) What I understand is that as nonlocal does not exist in 2.7, it is being treated as global in your code execution. Hence all the things in inner() affecting a='global'.